# Fragment shader does not behave the same between WebGL and Three.js => migration failure

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, transparent, fragment-shader

I have a big issue by trying to "port" a fragment shader from WebGL into Three.JS. First, I managed to apply a concentric halo effect within a square by using a fragment shader across WebGL here : [unitary test successfully managed by WebGL](http://hugo.machefer.free.fr/halo-webGL.html). To summarize, I use a basic square based on *universal* array of vertex defined in JS along with the following texture coordinates :

```
vertices = [                            texvert = [
     2.0,  2.0,  0.0,                       1.0, 0.0,
    -2.0,  2.0,  0.0,                       0.0, 0.0,
     2.0, -2.0,  0.0,                       1.0, 1.0,
    -2.0, -2.0,  0.0                        0.0, 1.0
];                                      ]
```

Here is the source code for my fragment shader :

```
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main(void) {
    float distance = distance(vTextureCoord, vec2(0.5, 0.5));
    float att = 1.8 * (distance - 0.005) ;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, att);
}
```

So far, so good. However, migrating this "raw" shader into Three.JS led to unexpected behavior ([unitary test badly managed by Three.JS](http://hugo.machefer.free.fr/halo-threeJS.html)). So what's wrong with my use case ?

By the way, here is the way I proceeded across ThreeJS t o create mesh and material :

```
        var squareGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        squareGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(2.0,  2.0, 0.0));
        squareGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-2.0,  2.0, 0.0));
        squareGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-2.0, -2.0, 0.0));
        squareGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(2.0, -2.0, 0.0));
        squareGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(0, 1, 2, 3));

        var myMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            attributes: attributes,
            vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vs' ).textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fs' ).textContent,
            side:THREE.DoubleSide
        });
        myMaterial.transparent = "true";
```

### ----------------------

> Your three.js example is throwing console errors. You need to fix
>   those. 2. You should update to the current version of three.js. 3. the
>   current version of three.js does not support quads. Use
>   THREE.PlaneGeometry() instead of creating your own geometry. – 
>   WestLangley 2 days ago

1. Example has been updated: no more console logs (apart from one: THREE.WebGLRenderer 66)
2. Three.JS has been upgraded yet to current/last version => release 66.
3. new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20,20) has been used according to expert advice

But the result remains the same however: black screen. Instead of expected concentric HALO effect. I keep wondering why 'att' parameter diverges between WebGL and Three.JS shader...

Comment: 1. Your three.js example is throwing console errors. You need to fix those. 2. You should update to the current version of three.js. 3. the current version of three.js does not support quads. Use `THREE.PlaneGeometry()` instead of creating your own geometry.

Comment: You edited demo still throws errors in the console.

Comment: This should get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh3Fj/. The rest you will have to do yourself.